# Does IsReadOnly forbid you from internally changing a custom IList object?

Tags: c#, .net

Remarks for [`IList.IsReadOnly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.isreadonly.aspx) state the following:

> A collection that is read-only does not allow the addition, removal, or modification of elements after the collection is created.

Does this mean that a custom class implementing IList cannot add or remove elements internally or does it just forbid users from doing it using the interface mothods?

If internal modifications are allowed, does that mean that code that expects an `IList` with `IsReadOnly` true to never change is inherently broken?

If internal modifications are not allowed, does that mean that it is impossible to write a valid `IList` which can change internally, but not allow users to modify it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645181%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> A collection that is read-only is simply a collection with a wrapper that prevents modifying the collection; therefore, if changes are made to the underlying collection, the read-only collection reflects those changes.

For another type, there's nothing to stop you exposing a truly immutable collection as `IList<T>` with that property returning true, but you don't have to.

We can also see that cases from the framework library that return true for `IsReadOnly` often allow the inner collection to be mutated.

```
List<int> initialList = new List<int> { 1 };
IList<int> readOnly = new ReadOnlyCollection<int>(initialList);
Console.WriteLine(readOnly.Count); // 1
Console.WriteLine(readOnly.IsReadOnly); // True
initialList.Add(2);
Console.WriteLine(readOnly.Count); // 2
```

Really, `IsReadOnly` tells you that the mutating methods like `Add` and the setter side of the indexer will fail, not that the object is immutable through all means.

An interesting consideration in this regard: Some places within the framework libraries themselves need read-only lists that are indeed truly read-only. Their public interface returns either `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` or `IReadOnlyList<T>` (e.g. `BlockExpression.Expressions` returns `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`) but they don't trust read-only collections passed to them. They use an internal type called `TrueReadOnlyCollection<T>` which is created as a wrapper of a fresh array, copied on construction so nothing else can change it. That type is trusted to never change and so can be shared between uses, but all other cases aren't.

Comment: @АндрейБеньковский yes, two different ways of phrasing it in my head when I wrote it, and I ended up typing a mismash of the two :)

Answer (score 4):

Internal code can indeed change it.

The `IsReadOnly` indicates that the list cannot be directly changed via that interface.

I agree that "code that expects an `IList` with `IsReadOnly` true to never change is inherently broken".

Microsoft has introduced the [`ImmutableList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467185%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) class, and perhaps this is one of the reasons.

`IReadOnlyList` to the rescue? Er, unfortunately no:

```
List<int> test = new List<int> {1};
IReadOnlyList<int> readOnly = test; // Because List<T> implements IReadOnlyList<int>.

Console.WriteLine(readOnly[0]);  // Prints 1.
test[0] = 2;
Console.WriteLine(readOnly[0]);  // Prints 2. Oops.
```

It's for these reasons that some time ago [I proposed that we should not declare interfaces for immutable types](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189473/do-not-declare-interfaces-for-immutable-objects).

And here's another example using `List<T>.AsReadOnly()`. This demonstrates that you can mutate a list with `IReadOnly` set true by using only built-in .Net types:

```
Console.WriteLine(shouldBeReadOnly.IsReadOnly);  // Readonly? Yep! This prints True.
Console.WriteLine(shouldBeReadOnly[0]);    // Prints 1.
Console.WriteLine(shouldBeReadOnly.Count); // Prints 1.
test[0] = 2;
test.Add(-1);
Console.WriteLine(shouldBeReadOnly[0]);    // Prints 2. Oops. It wasn't readonly at all.
Console.WriteLine(shouldBeReadOnly.Count); // Prints 2.
```

Note that you can change the number of elements as well as the elements themselves.

Comment: here you are modifying the value of the "plain" list, not the readonly one. Simply assigning it to a IReadOnlyList<T> will not make it readonly.

Comment: @Balázs The point is that you can't rely on a readonly list being immutable (which is the question in the OP).

Comment: @Balázs This, in a way, was my question. So he's right on point.

Comment: I'm saying that by doing this: `IReadOnlyList<int> readOnly = test;` you are not making the list readonly. Like this, you are only assigning an object reference to another. This assignment will not set the `IsReadOnly` property to `true`. Instead, it will prevent mutation by hiding `Add()` and other members, If you did this: `readOnly.Add(8)` this wouldn't have compiled.
Apart from that, you if you tried to modify the value like so: `readOnly[0] = 98;` this would also result in a compiler error, since there is no setter defined on the indexer,

Comment: And as a side note, I have never ever seen anyone exposing an inmutable collection as a list. That's why `IEnumerable<T>` exists; afterall, it's not the outside code's business to access elements by index or even have an idea of what structure the containing class uses for holding elements.

Comment: @MatthewWatson yeah, perhaps I do. (no sarcasm)

Comment: @Balázs I'll explain a bit more: The question is: Can a method which receives a parameter of type `IList<T>` with `IsReadOnly` set to true assume that the list is immutable? Or can a method which receives a parameter of type `IReadOnlyList<int>` assume that the list is immutable and will NEVER CHANGE? And the answer to both of those is: "No, it cannot".

Comment: I just noticed that `IReadOnlyList<T>` does *not* implement `Ilist<T>`. So `IReadOnlyList<T>` never actually makes a claim that it will not get changed after construction. It also doesn't have a `IsReadOnly` property.

Comment: @relatively_random `IReadOnlyList<T>` was just another example of a class that is readonly but not immutable. But see my other example using `List<T>.AsReadOnly()` which returns an externally-mutable readonly list.

Comment: @Balázs "I have never ever seen anyone exposing an inmutable collection as a list" - That's not what we're discussing. We're talking about readonly collections which are mutable.

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes, I agree with that but I was approaching the question from a technical side rather than the theorical one. But being readonly != being immutable. If you write a class which contains some readonly property, that is an instance of another class, you can mutate the contained one. You just can't change it's reference. There is a conceptual difference between the two.

Comment: @MatthewWatson OK, then I'll just treat this one as a misunderstanding :)

Comment: I agree with Jon Hanna and Matthew Watson about the `ReadOnlyCollection` in the framework as an example of a collection that declares itself read-only but is not immutable. However, the documentation of the `IList.IsReadOnly` property is different from the `ReadOnlyCollection<T>.IList.IsReadOnly` documentation in that the latter defines a read-only collection as a read-only wrapper around an ordinary collection, whereas the former makes no such presumption.

Answer (score 1):

A class implementing `IList` with `IsReadOnly==true` promises that it does not change, both internally and from the outside, after being created.  Of course, it is up to the implementer to keep that promise. If he fails, then the implementation of the `IList` is broken, not the code using it.

One can argue that this should only hold for explicit interface implementation. I would still consider such an implementation as broken.

Comment: In other words, you believe it is impossible to write a valid mutable `IList` with `IsReadOnly` true?

Comment: I think he's right that it would not be a valid implementation.

Comment: It promises no such thing. This is completely at odds with both the documentation and implementations provided by the framework.